# Wiggle subsequence from leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge

This is the [Wiggle Subsequence](https://leetcode.com/problems/wiggle-subsequence/description/) problem from leetcode.com:

> A sequence of numbers is called a **wiggle sequence** if the differences between successive numbers strictly alternate between positive and negative. The first difference (if one exists) may be either positive or negative. A sequence with fewer than two elements is trivially a wiggle sequence.
>
> For example, [1,7,4,9,2,5] is a wiggle sequence because the differences (6,-3,5,-7,3) are alternately positive and negative. In contrast, [1,4,7,2,5] and [1,7,4,5,5] are not wiggle sequences, the first because its first two differences are positive and the second because its last difference is zero.
>
> Given a sequence of integers, return the length of the longest subsequence that is a wiggle sequence. A subsequence is obtained by deleting some number of elements (eventually, also zero) from the original sequence, leaving the remaining elements in their original order.

The solution is inspired by an \$O(n\log n)\$ answer to [How to determine the longest increasing subsequence using dynamic programming?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2631726)

```
class Solution(object):
    def wiggleMaxLength(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if not nums or len(nums) == 1:
            return len(nums)
        current_num, prev_num = nums[0], nums[0]
        count, trend = 0, None
        for current_num in nums:
            if not trend:
                if current_num > prev_num:
                    trend = "down_to_up"
                    count += 2
                elif current_num < prev_num:
                    trend = "up_to_down"
                    count += 2
            elif trend == "down_to_up":
                if current_num < prev_num:
                    count += 1
                    trend = "up_to_down"
            elif trend == "up_to_down":
                if current_num > prev_num:
                    prev_num = current_num
                    count += 1
                    trend = "down_to_up"
            prev_num = current_num
        if trend == None:
            count = 1
        return count
```

Comment: According to [how to ask](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/checklist-for-how-to-write-a-good-code-review-question), your question is not correct. The following code doesn't work for obvious reasons, but here is an example to prove it : [1, 7, 4, 8, 9, 2, 5] returns 6, and the correct answer is 4.

Comment: What is the return value supposed to mean?  It's called `count`, but what's it a count of?  (I tried following the "Question" link, but it's a mostly-empty page, so it didn't help).

Comment: @TobySpeight It is supposed to be the length of the longuest wiggle subsequence, in given sequence. But OP's code doesn't work, and should go on stackoverflow probably.

Comment: @IMCoins: The subsequence doesn't have to be contiguous: the challenge page gives the example `[1,17,5,10,13,15,10,5,16,8]` which has wiggle subsequences of length 7 for example `[1,17,10,13,10,16,8]`. I edited the question to quote some more of the problem, in particular "A subsequence is obtained by deleting some number of elements from the original sequence".

Comment: Thanks for the insight @GarethRees . I'm then going to review the code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The special case:

   ```
   if not nums or len(nums) == 1:
   ```

   can be simplified to:

   ```
   if not nums:
   ```

   because the case `len(nums) == 1` is already handled correctly by the main code.
2. Instead of starting with `count = 0`, setting `count += 2` when a trend is found for the first time, and having an adjustment at the end if no trend was found, you could start with `count = 1`, set `count += 1` when a trend is found for the first time, and remove the adjustment.
3. There is no need to initialise `current_num = nums[0]` because this immediately gets overwritten by the `for current_num in ...` loop.
4. There is an unnecessary assignment of `prev_num = current_num` in one of the branches.
5. Using the strings `"down_to_up"` and `"up_to_down"` to represent the current trend is risky: if you made a typo and wrote `"up_to_dwon"` somewhere, then the code would be broken but Python would not detect this. It would be better to use global constants, for example

   ```
   _DOWN_TO_UP = "down to up"
   _UP_TO_DOWN = "up to down"
   ```

   and then if you make a typo like `_UP_TO_DWON` you will get a `NameError` from Python.
6. Now the main logic of the function looks like this:

   ```
   if not trend:
       if current_num > prev_num:
           trend = _DOWN_TO_UP
           count += 1
       elif current_num < prev_num:
           trend = _UP_TO_DOWN
           count += 1
   elif trend == _DOWN_TO_UP:
       if current_num < prev_num:
           trend = _UP_TO_DOWN
           count += 1
   elif trend == _UP_TO_DOWN:
       if current_num > prev_num:
           trend = _DOWN_TO_UP
           count += 1
   prev_num = current_num
   ```

   There is a lot of repetition here. In particular, on each branch we check to see if the trend has changed direction, and if it has, then we update `trend` and increment `count`. So we could refactor it so that we work out the new trend first, and then compare it with the old trend, like this:

   ```
   # Work out current trend
   if current_num > prev_num:
       current_trend = _DOWN_TO_UP
   elif current_num < prev_num:
       current_trend = _UP_TO_DOWN
   else: # current_num == prev_num
       current_trend = 0

   # Compare with previous trend
   if current_trend != 0 and current_trend != trend:
       trend = current_trend
       count += 1
   prev_num = current_num
   ```
7. In the case `current_num == prev_num` we know that the trend does not change, and so there can't be a change to `trend`, so it would make sense to test this first, and so avoid the test `current_trend != 0`, like this:

   ```
   if current_num != prev_num:
       # Work out current trend
       if current_num > prev_num:
           current_trend = _DOWN_TO_UP
       else:
           current_trend = _UP_TO_DOWN

       # Compare with previous trend
       if current_trend != trend:
           trend = current_trend
           count += 1
       prev_num = current_num
   ```
8. And now we can make a further simplification by using `True` instead of `_DOWN_TO_UP` and `False` instead of `_UP_TO_DOWN`:

   ```
   if current_num != prev_num:
       current_trend = current_num > prev_num
       if current_trend != trend:
           trend = current_trend
           count += 1
       prev_num = current_num
   ```
9. After making this change, it should be clear that `prev_trend` would be a better name than `trend`, for parallelism with `prev_num`.

   ```
   def wiggleMaxLength(self, nums):
       "Return length of longest wiggle subsequence of nums."
       if not nums:
           return 0
       count = 1
       prev_num = nums[0]
       prev_trend = None
       for current_num in nums:
           if current_num != prev_num:
               current_trend = current_num > prev_num
               if current_trend != prev_trend:
                   prev_trend = current_trend
                   count += 1
               prev_num = current_num
       return count
   ```

   It would make sense to stop here, as the revised code is already a lot simpler than the original. But if you are comfortable with Python iterators then you might want to read on to see how the functions and recipes in the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module can be used to further simplify the code.
10. First, we can avoid the `current_num != prev_num` test by using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group identical numbers together:

    ```
    from itertools import groupby

    def wiggleMaxLength(self, nums):
        "Return length of longest wiggle subsequence of nums."
        if not nums:
            return 0
        nums = (n for n, _ in groupby(nums))
        prev_num = next(nums)
        count = 1
        prev_trend = None
        for current_num in nums:
            current_trend = current_num > prev_num
            if current_trend != prev_trend:
                prev_trend = current_trend
                count += 1
            prev_num = current_num
        return count
    ```
11. Now that we have an iterator over groups of identical numbers, we can use the [`pairwise` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the itertools documentation to iterate over adjacent pairs of numbers, avoiding the need to assign to `prev_num`.

    ```
    from itertools import groupby, tee

    def pairwise(iterable):
        "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
        a, b = tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return zip(a, b)

    def wiggleMaxLength(self, nums):
        "Return length of longest wiggle subsequence of nums."
        if not nums:
            return 0
        nums = (n for n, _ in groupby(nums))
        count = 1
        prev_trend = None
        for prev_num, current_num in pairwise(nums):
            current_trend = current_num > prev_num
            if current_trend != prev_trend:
                prev_trend = current_trend
                count += 1
        return count
    ```
12. Now we can construct an iterator over the trends:

    ```
        trends = (cur > prev for prev, cur in pairwise(nums))
    ```

    and apply [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to *this* iterator, thus grouping identical trends together and avoiding the need for `current_trend` and `prev_trend`. In fact, all we have to do now is count the groups of identical trends.

    ```
    def wiggleMaxLength(self, nums):
        "Return length of longest wiggle subsequence of nums."
        if not nums:
            return 0
        nums = (n for n, _ in groupby(nums))
        trends = (cur > prev for prev, cur in pairwise(nums))
        return 1 + sum(1 for _ in groupby(trends))
    ```
13. This could be written as a single expression:

    ```
    def wiggleMaxLength(self, nums):
        "Return length of longest wiggle subsequence of nums."
        return bool(nums) + sum(1 for _ in groupby(
            a > b for a, b in pairwise(n for n, _ in groupby(nums))))
    ```

    (But only if you like that kind of code.)